# Form Request Validation not working. It just loads the home page in postman

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to validate input data with a custom form request.
The form request name is UpdatePassword. And i try to run the code by injecting it in my updatePassword() function in my Api/AuthController. I and it just redirects back to home page

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Api;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdatePassword extends FormRequest
{


    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|exists:users,email',
            'old_password' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'
        ];
    }
}
```

My controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Requests\Api\UpdatePassword;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class AuthController extends controller
{

    public function updatePassword(UpdatePassword $request){


            dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

My Exceptions/Handler.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

  }
```

Here is my route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api'], function (){

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function (){

        Route::post('changePassword', 'AuthController@updatePassword');
    });
});

Here is the postman request and response  

[![Here is the postman request and response][1]][1]


when I
```

try to run the code in postman it as an ajax request it doesn't work. the validation doesn't work. it just renders the home page. localhost:8000

Comment: where you have define your API routes?

Comment: @sandy I don't understand your question

Comment: Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function (){

    Route::post('changePassword', 'AuthController@updatePassword');
}); in which file you have write this?

Comment: I don't think your request is hitting the right controller. As @sandy says, you need to tell us where your routes are defined.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests you can refer this link

Comment: could you show your `routes/api.php`

Comment: @sandy this is my route

Comment: you already define your routes in API.php file so i think you dont need to add "namespace" there

Comment: @sandy. The namespace is because I defined my AuthController in ../controllers/Api/AuthController.

Comment: Are you calling the route from postman with the `Accept: application/json` HTTP header (or the equivalent `Content-Type` one)?

Comment: Try doing this `public function updatePassword(Request $request) {
            dd($request->all());
    }` to make sure if the problem is with custom request validation or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If validation fails while using a Form request, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. That's why you are redirecting back to the page instead of the response JSON.

Laravel have one protected method "failedValidation" method. You need to overwrite this method in your form request class which is UpdatePassword.php in case above by adding the below code snippet to.
.
.
.

```
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
    
    
    
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
    }
```

Comment: "a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location", i see, that's the why dd() is show nothing

Answer (score 6):

Are you calling the route from postman with the `Accept: application/json` HTTP header (or the equivalent `Content-Type` one)?

If you don't put that Laravel doesn't know that you want a json response and would redirect you to the homepage (I think it will default to it because you don't have a referrer header set on your request) with errors in the session.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try with this validator syntex. i have used.
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [         
        'email' => 'required|email', 
        'password' => 'required',   
        ]);
        $temp = $validator->errors()->all();
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['Status' => 
  false,'Message'=>$temp[0],'Data' => '','Status_code' =>"401" ]);            
        }
```

Comment: I want to create a custom Validation request. I don't want to validate in the controller